# How to reset array indexes in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using React & Firebase database for web.

In the below code, `dbRef` points to a Firebase database tree containing an **array** of strings. Some of this array's elements have been removed which has resulted in null indexes.

```
[
  "0": "first",
  "1": "next",
  "6": "skipped indexes 2 - 5"
]
```

I'm currently doing:

```
dbRef.set([...currentList, newItem])
```

However, I'd like to ensure that the array passed to `set` does not have any `null` indexes. What is the best way to do this in JS?  (I'm using babel if it matters)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing arrays in firebase for the exact reason you're trying to solve this issue. See: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: @MathewBerg, Thank you for pointing this out.  I'll be using objects instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the entries that it doesn't have anymore:

```
// In ES2015+
theArray = theArray.filter((_, index) => theArray.hasOwnProperty(index));

// In ES5 and earlier
theArray = theArray.filter(function(_, index) { return theArray.hasOwnProperty(index); });
```

Example:

```js
var theArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
delete theArray[2];
console.log("before", JSON.stringify(theArray));
theArray = theArray.filter((_, index) => theArray.hasOwnProperty(index));
console.log("after", JSON.stringify(theArray));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Is there a reason using `hasOwnProperty(index)` is better/safer than using `.filter(val => val)`?

Comment: Yeah, I see now.  If `val` is `falsey` then it will be removed by `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way

```
testArray.filter(function(val){return val});
```

Comment: This will also remove entries that are present but contain `""`, `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, or `false`.